# How to set variable equal to for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x

This is my code. How do I make bownew = multiple rows of *'s? I do not want to just print for x in range(height):print bownew. I want bownew to be equal to the for x in range(height). How can this be done?

```
height = int(input("Enter an odd number greater than 4: "));
column = height * 2;

screen = [];
bownew = ""

def bow(height):
    for x in range(height):
        screen.append(["*"]*column);

bow(height);

for i in screen:
    bownew = " ".join(i)
print(bownew)
```

Comment: There is no need for semi-colons in Python (at least how you are using them).

Comment: is it just to have multiple code lines on one line?

Comment: @paulandshadow Yes, that's the only time they're necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a `for` loop, `join` wants the list as the argument. And if you want it to have multiple lines, join them with newlines.

```
bownew = "\n".join(screen)
```

You also need to make `screen` a list of strings, not a list of lists:

```
def bow(height):
    for x in range(height):
        screen.append("*" * column);
```

The whole script:

```
height = int(input("Enter an odd number greater than 4: "));
column = height * 2;

screen = [];
bownew = ""

def bow(height):
    for x in range(height):
        screen.append("*" * column);

bow(height);

bownew = "\n".join(screen)

print(bownew)
```

Test run:

```
$ python test.py
Enter an odd number greater than 4: 5
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

Comment: but i want there to be multiple rows of that. There should be the inputed height variable as the number of rows

Comment: Join them with newlines instead of spaces.

Comment: it does not work. Says expected string but got list.

Comment: I think the problem is the way you create `screen`. It's a list of lists, not a list of strings. Try `"*"*column` instead of `["*"]*column`

Comment: still not working "list obj cannot be interp. as int"

Comment: It's working for me. I posted the whole script that I tested.

Comment: You could also build the `screen` list without a for loop, and then just built the whole string with one `join` call: `bownew = '\n'.join([("*" * column)] * height)`

Comment: Oh! i see where I screwed up. Stupid mistake (wrong named variable). Thanks for the help!

Comment: BTW, why do you make `height` a parameter to the function, but not `column`? It's best to avoid using global variables, so the function should take both `height` and `column` as arguments, and return `screen` as a result.

Comment: I'm not going to do your homework for you. Try to figure it out. In a bowtie, each row will be different, not all the same.

Comment: If you run into more problems trying to do that, post a new question.

Comment: this isn't homework :P I'm doing all this for fun. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The comment you just deleted looked like a homework exercise. Anyway, the only way to learn how to program is to program, not by copying answers that someone else posts here.

Comment: nope its a CCC 2001 question. look it up if you don't believe me

Answer (score 0):

**1**.There might be a simpler solution, that requires no use of **for loop**

```
height = int('Enter an odd number greater than 4: ')
column = height * 2

row = '*' * column
bownew = [row] * height
bownew = '\n'.join(bownew)

print(bownew)
```

,and I have tested it, it works.

```
Enter an odd number greater than 4: 5
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

**2**. As for the question(*How to set variable equal to for loop in python?*), I suspect that you can not make a variable equal to any loop **unless** you use `def` .

The use of `def` will be

```
height = int('Enter an odd number greater than 4: ')
column = height * 2

def bownew(height, column):
    for i in range(height):
        print('*' * column)

bownew(height, column)
```

This should give you the same result.

*Happy coding, hope this is helpful.*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please enter your code directly in your answer instead of in an image.